# How to pass configuration into forRoot

Tags: node.js, typescript, yaml, config, nestjs

How can I pass configuration object into `forRoot()` in AppModule? Is there a way to access `configService` if there is not `constructor` in the module?

`config.yml`:

```
smtp:
  host: 'smtp.host.com'
  port: 10
  secure: true
  auth:
    user: 'username'
    auth: 'password'
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MailModule.forRoot(), // I want to pass configuration here
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd need an async registration method like `forRootAsync`, but it's up to the module creator to provide this method. If this method does exist you can use a factory and `inject` to create a class-like provider system that Nest can inject with [as shown in the database docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration). Without knowing which mailing module you're working with, I can't say more if it supports this or not.

Without that async registration method, it's not possible to use DI in the `forRoot`.

Comment: I was thinking about using `config` package but I reckon that it wasn't  the best practice if there is a built in solution in the framework

Answer (score 0):

I installed `config` package and used it like so:

```
import * as config from 'config';

const smtpConfig = config.get('smtp');

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailModule.forRoot(smtpConfig),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```